# Node/Express ¿como generar un pdf con datos de una tabla?

Tags: nodejs, express, pdf, tablas, exportar

tengo esta tabla y necesito generar un pdf con esos datos. he probado con pdfmake, hice un pdf pero lo que me falta es que aparezcan los datos de la tabla.
tienen alguna idea de como se hace? u otra libreria pdf que sea algo mas facil

```
<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" style="width: 131px;">Descripcion</th>
          <th scope="col" style="width: 136px;">Garantia por Contenedor</th>
          <th scope="col" style="width: 100px;">Cantidad</th>
          <th scope="col" style="width: 264px;">Unitario arriendo 
            <br/> mensual no fraccionable</th>
          <th scope="col" style="width:188px ;">Subtotal arriendo</th>
          <th scope="col" style="width: 86px;"> Destino</th>
          <th scope="col" style="width: 140px;">Unitario flete </th>
          <th scope="col" style="width: 145px;">Subtotal flete</th>
          <th scope="col" style="width: 70px;">Quitar</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <% if (data) { %> 
          <% for (var i = 0; i< data.length; i++) { %> 
               </tr>
              <td>  <%= data[i].descripcion%></td>
              <td>  <%= data[i].garantia%></td>
              <td>  <%= data[i].cantidad%></td>
              <td> <%= data[i].arriendoUnitario%></td>
              <td>  <%= data[i].subtotalarriendo%></td>
              <td>  <%= data[i].destino%></td>
              <td>  <%= data[i].unitarioflete%></td>
              <td>  <%= data[i].subtotalflete%></td>
              <td> <a href="/quitar/<%= data[i].id_presupuesto %>" class="btn btn-danger">Quitar</a></td>

               <tr>
                <% } %>
                <% } %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Aca en la tabla que hice a partir de pdfmake playground, quiero insertar algunos datos de la tabla de arriba

```
module.exports =  {
    
    
    content: [
        
        
        {
            style: 'tableExample',
            table: {
                body: [
                    ['Item', 'Cantidad', 'Descripcion', ' UN', 'P.Unit. Neto', 'Subtotal'],
                    ['datos 1', 'datos 2', 'datos 3','datos 4 ','datos 5', 'dato 6']
                ]
            }
        },]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrás que convertir cada fila de tu arreglo data en un arreglo de valores.

Ejemplo:

```
const list = [[1,
    100,
    'test',
    'Kg',
    200,
    90000
],[
    2,
    200,
    'test 1',
    'Kg',
    400,
    18000
]];
```

**Uso:**

```
   content: [
    
    
    {
        style: 'tableExample',
        table: {
            body: [
                ['Item', 'Cantidad', 'Descripcion', ' UN', 'P.Unit. Neto', 'Subtotal'],
                ...list 
            ]
        }
    },]}
```

Espero te sirva!

Para mayor información, visita la documentación

https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/document-definition-object/tables/